# Importing a class by referring to it with a variable?

Tags: python, import, python-import

Edit: This question was on the assumption that I could import parts of modules without importing the whole module. It turns out that isn't the case so I decided to just import the whole module with `from ex45_extras import *` anyway. That makes this question pointless, but I decided to not delete this question so that some other beginner with the same question can come here and find out the sad truth: You can't import modules as parts anyways

The following is the original question:

I'm a beginner so sry for the noob question. I want to call specific classes from a module with a variable. I don't want to call the whole module. And I need to do this using this class Nav() to control which classes are being imported. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better solution?

```
class Nav():
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class Nav")
    
    def play(self):
        current_scene_name = "A()" # this is where the variable is defined
        from ex45_extras import current_scene_name # <- this is the one


x = Nav()
x.play()
```

Currently it's raising this error:

```
This is class Nav
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\LPTHW_Exs\ex45\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    x.play()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\LPTHW_Exs\ex45\test.py", line 7, in play
    from ex45_extras import current_scene_name
ImportError: cannot import name 'current_scene_name' from 'ex45_extras' (D:\Programming\Python\LPTHW_Exs\ex45\ex45_extras.py)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You can import a module locally in a function and use "getattr" to retrieve a contained class or function (which are attributes of the module).

Comment: @MichaelButscher wouldn't that be the same as importing the module beforehand in the usual way?

Comment: @quamrana k I did that now

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with `ex45_extras`. What do you expect `current_scene_name` to be?

Comment: @Necryl The only difference is that the module name wouldn't appear as global variable if it is imported locally.

Comment: @quamrana I expect it to be taken as A()
ex45_extras has a class named A(). It works fine when I import it normally

Comment: @MichaelButscher oh I see, welp, that isn't what I'm going for but thx

Comment: By the way: It is not possible to import anything from a module without importing the whole module anyway. With "from ... import ..." this is hidden but in the background the whole module is first imported before requested items are taken from it and provided.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hmm, that kinda makes my question pointless. I'm thinking of just importing the whole module the normal way after all. That will solve my problem for now but should I delete this question? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: @Necryl I think that other beginners may also assume that importing parts of a module would be possible and useful. At least it can tell them that this isn't true.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that makes sense, I'll leave it as it is then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names don't have a trailing `()` suffix — that's how you create an instance of one (i.e. by calling it).

Anyhow, if `ex45_extras.py` defines a class named `A`:

```
class A:
    pass
```

Then you could `import` the class via a string containing its name, and then create an instance of it as shown below:

```
class Nav():
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is class Nav")

    def play(self):
        import ex45_extras

        current_scene_name = 'A' # this is where the variable is defined
        class_ = getattr(ex45_extras, current_scene_name)  # Get class.
        instance = class_()  # Create instance of class.
        print(f'{instance=}')  # -> instance=<ex45_extras.A object at 0x010D4838>


x = Nav()
x.play()
```

Comment: looks like Python imports the whole module anyways so I guess I'll settle for this. Thank you

Comment: I know of no way to not `import` an entire module, because that involves executing the whole thing. All you really have control over is the visibility of its contents in the scope of your own code. In my answer the module name, class name, and instance name are all local variables in the `play()` function and not accessible outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

guess it's because you're trying to import an string `"A()"` instead of a class `A()`

Comment: I don't know if that is a problem but it's not looking into that anyways, it's taking the variable name as if it's the name of the class to be imported